# How to identify scroll events top, right, bottom, right separately | angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to identify scroll events for top, right, bottom and left separately. I have a table which has mouse up and down events, which handles fixing some of the table rows and columns, trying to achieve the same using scroll event.

I am cloning this directive and trying to add additional feature such as scroll, which holds the same functionality as click.

[example](https://jatinmarwah.github.io/angular-table-freezepane/app/#/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you probably need to identify the scroll direction manually inside your scroll or click (the place where you really catch the mouse movement) event handler by comparing **top**, **bottom**, **left** and **right** offsets of the window. For example, for **up** and **down** directions you will need something like this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/klEnqdaR6JoXY5MmZwMe).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
return function($scope, element, attrs) {
    $scope.lastScrollTop = 0;
    $scope.direction = "";
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
        $scope.st = window.pageYOffset;
        if ($scope.st > $scope.lastScrollTop) {
            $scope.direction = "down";
        } else {
            $scope.direction = "up";
        }

        $scope.lastScrollTop = $scope.st;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log($scope.direction);
     });
  };
});
```

Code example taken from [here](http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/02/how-to-determine-direction-of-scroll.html#.WsHz5ta-kx8).

The same for **left** and **right** directions, just use `pageXOffset` value.